# find duplicates in a column, return the unique item and list its corresponding values from another column in python

Tags: python, no-duplicates

I would like to remove duplicates from column 1 and return in colum 2 the related list of values associated to each unique item using python.

The input is

```
1 2
Jack London 'Son of the Wolf'
Jack London 'Chris Farrington'
Jack London 'The God of His Fathers'
Jack London 'Children of the Frost'
William Shakespeare  'Venus and Adonis' 
William Shakespeare 'The Rape of Lucrece'
Oscar Wilde 'Ravenna'
Oscar Wilde 'Poems'
```

while the output should be

```
1 2
Jack London 'Son of the Wolf, Chris Farrington, Able Seaman, The God of His Fathers,Children of the Frost'
William Shakespeare 'The Rape of Lucrece,Venus and Adonis' 
Oscar Wilde 'Ravenna,Poems'
```

where the second column harbouring the sum of values associated to each item.
I tried the set() function on dictionary

```
dic={'Jack London': 'Son of the Wolf', 'Jack London': 'Chris Farrington', 'Jack London': 'The God of His Fathers'}
set(dic)
```

but it returned only the first key of dictionary

```
set(['Jack London'])
```

Comment: How are you dividing columns?

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't think it matters, he's not asking how to parse the input.

Comment: It's tempting to just write code that would do this for you, but I don't think you or I would learn much by that. Here is an example that I think would be helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `itertools.groupby` since your list is sorted.

```
rows = [('1', '2'),
        ('Jack London', 'Son of the Wolf'),
        ('Jack London', 'Chris Farrington'),
        ('Jack London', 'The God of His Fathers'),
        ('Jack London', 'Children of the Frost'),
        ('William Shakespeare', 'Venus and Adonis'),
        ('William Shakespeare', 'The Rape of Lucrece'),
        ('Oscar Wilde', 'Ravenna'),
        ('Oscar Wilde', 'Poems')]
# I'm not sure how you get here, but that's where you get

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = groupby(rows, itemgetter(0))
result = {group:', '.join([value[1] for value in values]) for group, values in grouped}
```

This gives you a result of:

```
In [1]: pprint(result)
{'1': '2',
 'Jack London': 'Son of the Wolf, Chris Farrington, The God of His Fathers, '
                'Children of the Frost',
 'Oscar Wilde': 'Ravenna, Poems',
 'William Shakespeare': 'Venus and Adonis, The Rape of Lucrece'}
```

Comment: I think the following results are closer to the desired specifiction: result = {group:[x[1:][0] for x in values] for group,values in grouped}

Comment: @JimDennis True. I should probably even do `data = {group:[col[1] for col in values] for group,values in grouped}; result = "{} {}".format(row[0], ' '.join(row[1:]) for row in data)`

Comment: Yes, technically he's saying that "the output should be" ... but I'm assuming that he's actually more interested in the resulting data structure rather than the literal output.  My suggestion, and augurar's answer which I've upvoted, are predicated on that interpretation of his question rather than the literal request for "output."

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a dictionary can only contain one value per key.  But that value can be a collection of items:

```
>>> d = {'Jack London': ['Son of the Wolf', 'Chris Farrington']}
>>> d['Jack London']
['Son of the Wolf', 'Chris Farrington']
```

To construct such a dictionary from a sequence of key-value pairs, you can do something like this:

```
dct = {}
for author, title in items:
    if author not in dct:
        # Create a new entry for the author
        dct[author] = [title]
    else:
        # Add another item to the existing entry
        dct[author].append(title)
```

The loop body can be made more concise like so:

```
dct = {}
for author, title in items:
    dct.setdefault(author, []).append(title)
```